# jQuery <li> index finding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="es-carousel">
    <ul>
        <li><a><img src="something157.jpg" ></a></li>
        <li><a><img src="blabla.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a><img src="nonsense.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a><img src="cthulhu.jpg"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The html is above.

The jQuery selector I have for finding the img with the right src:

```
$(".es-carousel").find("ul li a img[src*='something']")
```

The problem is I need to find the index of the li that this image is in.
(I plan on use .index() for that) I have no idea how to select that precise li which has that image.

Can anyone show me the right direction or give me an idea? All help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to use `:has()` and `index()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) would help you in this case

```
$(".es-carousel").find("ul li:has(a img[src*='something'])").index();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this elegant solution

Answer (score 4):

Start at the img and work your way up:

`$(".es-carousel").find("img[src*='something']").parents('li').index();`

http://jsfiddle.net/zyvTD/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the parents method of jQuery to get the appropriate li element which contains the img that you are selecting.
Try the below selector.

```
$(".es-carousel").find("ul li a img[src*='something']").parents("li");
```

Thanks,

Jothi

Answer (score -1):

Make an each function with an i/index parameter, in the each you search in the children for that image, and where the image is found you output the index.

Sample:

```
var somethingVar = XxXX;

jQuery('.my-list li').each(function(index){
    var foundImage = jQuery(this).find('a img[src*='somethingVar']');
    if(foundImage.length) {
        console.log('Your index is ' + index);
    }
})
```

Comment: Why would you loop? You are recreating `.index()`